# PHP Mail - receiving wrong words on the mail server

Tags: php, email, encoding

When I try to send mail from a web page - on the mail.bg and abv.bg mail I receive letters like this :

```
РќРѕРІРѕ
```

where I must receive "Ново"
What can I do so I can fix it - on gmail.com I receive the normal "Ново" and when I use echo - I also receive the normal "Ново" , but on the mail.bg and abv.bg - I receive this strange words...is there something wrong with the encoding ?

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64');
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'example@mail.bg';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
$subject = $_POST['subject'];


if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "$subject, $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message"; 
    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'. "\n\r\n";
    mail($to, '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($email_subject).'?=', $email_body, $headers);

    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');


} 

?>
```

When I try to send mail from a web page - on the mail.bg and abv.bg mail I receive letters like this :

```
РќРѕРІРѕ
```

where I must receive "Ново"
What can I do so I can fix it - on gmail.com I receive the normal "Ново" and when I use echo - I also receive the normal "Ново" , but on the mail.bg and abv.bg - I receive this strange words...is there something wrong with the encoding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your headers are specifying `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` but you have not applied `base64_encode` on your contents. (in your case `$email_body`)

On the other hand, please use `\r\n` to separate respective header lines

Hence, change the block

```
$headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'. "\n\r\n";
mail($to, '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($email_subject).'?=', $email_body, $headers);
```

to

```
$email_body=base64_encode($email_body);

$headers = "From: $myemail\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'. "\r\n";
mail($to, '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($email_subject).'?=', $email_body, $headers);
```

Alternatively, remove `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 specification`, like this:

```
//$email_body=base64_encode($email_body);

$headers = "From: $myemail\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'. "\r\n";
mail($to, '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($email_subject).'?=', $email_body, $headers);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help ! this one works for me - I do not need at all the base64 for the $headers - I was making it more complicated than it should be